# Error While trying to run Project : Unable to start debuggeing on the web server . The project is not configured to be debugged

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

i have created Project with Visual Studio 2003 and when i try to run my project i faced this problem .

i was search about it and read all solution that related to this problem but no luck

so please any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this error recently. It occurs basically due to a mess up in configuring your application in the IIS Server.

Make sure the following things are intact and your error will disappear:

1. Virtual directories in IIS need to bear the **same** **name** as its original application directory.
2. Check if your application pool is stopped. If so, start it. Also make sure the framework of the pool matches with that of your application.
3. Clear Temp files, Temp ASP files and restart your IIS.

Happy coding!